# loop issue when inviting users

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am having trouble finding out my mistake. In my app I am creating a user that is set as inactive and then sending to those users a mail invitation to join my app. I set it up to be able to send multiple invitations but it only send one on the X invitations. So if I invite 5 users, only on mail is sent and 1 user created instead of 5. I guess there is something wrong with my loop but cannot find what.. 
here is my code

views.py:

```
def TeamRegister2(request):
    InviteFormSet = formset_factory(InviteForm2)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = InviteFormSet(request.POST, prefix = 'pfix')

        if(formset.is_valid()):
            for i in formset:
                mail = i.cleaned_data['Email']
                user = MyUser(email = mail)
                password = MyUser.objects.make_random_password()
                user.set_password(password)
                user.is_active = False
                user.is_employee = True
                user.save()
                u1 = user.id
                a1 = MyUser.objects.get(email = request.user.email)
                a2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin = a1)
                a3 = a2.latest('id')
                a4 = a3.team_id
                a4.members.add(u1)

                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user':user,
                    'domain':current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                })
                mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please sign in to get access to the app'
                to_email = user.email
                email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                email.send()
            return HttpResponse('An email have been sent to each Team member asking them to join in')
        else:
            print("The entered form is not valid")

    else:
        formset = InviteFormSet(prefix= 'pfix')
    return render(request,'team_register.html', {'formset':formset})
```

form.py:

```
class InviteForm2(forms.Form):
    """
    Form for member email invite
    """
    Email = forms.EmailField(
                    widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                        'placeholder': "Member's mail",
                    }),
                    required=False)
```

team_register.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Invite your Team members</h2>
      <h3>You can choose up to 7 team members</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-style">
     <form method="post" class="form-inline">
       {% csrf_token %}

       {{ formset.management_form }}

       {% for form in formset %}
           <div class="link-formset">

                 {{ form.label_tag }}  {{ form }}
                 {% if field.help_text %}
                   <small style="display: none">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
                 {% endif %}
                 {% for error in field.errors %}
                   <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                 {% endfor %}

            </div>

        {% endfor %}

       <div>
         <input type="submit" value="Send Invitations" class="btn btn-primary"/>
       </div>

    </form>

</div>
</div>
         <!-- Include formset plugin - including jQuery dependency -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    $('.link-formset').formset({
        addText: 'add member',
        deleteText: 'remove'
             });
</script>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you show the relevant parts of `team_register.html`? Also, check the `request.POST` data by setting a breakpoint after `if request.method == 'POST'`, it doesn't look like anything is wrong with your loop so I suspect the wrong data is posted.

Comment: since you initialise the FormSet with only one form (not setting extra) I suspect you add new forms in a wrong way in your template. Your input fields must have all a different `name` attribute.

Comment: hi @dirkgroten I just added the HTML file ;)

Comment: Are you sure the indentation is as shown here, with the return at the same level as the for loop and not inside it?

Comment: Yes the views.py indentation is the same ! I copy/past and rechecked now

Comment: if you can access the `request.POST` in your console (print it or set a breakpoint), that would help. Or at least, load an initial form, add one extra form using the `add member` button and look at the resulting HTML in the browser. Note: I don't really understand some stuff in your template, where is `field` defined, like in `{{ field.help_text }}`? Shouldn't have anything to do with your issue though.

Comment: Hi sorry for the field.help it is code that I did not deleted from a previous test. When I get to the team_register.html I provide a mail let say 1@gmail.com then I add an extra from using add member and enter 2@gmail.com and click on Send invitations I am redirected to the http response  An email have been sent to each Team member asking them to join in. However only one mail is sent and create which is 2@gmail.com from the extra fiels

Comment: and if I add a third extra field and prvide 3@gmail.com only this one is created and not the 2 previous fields

Comment: understood that part. But to debug, you'll really have to look at the `request.POST` data (and probably the actual HTML in the browser debugger). Without those 2 things, it's going to be difficult to debug. So please, set a breakpoint as I told you before and print the `request.POST` in your console.

Comment: Ok I will learn about debug I don't know yet how to do it and come back

Comment: ok when I print request.POST i get : (Pdb) print(request.POST)
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['Z8ZgGpCrJLHAO0S60L9HvXbWVP4YY6gt84IKxTN1J13A9gMByGFd0gxoZwgf8Dvr'], 'pfix-T
OTAL_FORMS': ['1'], 'pfix-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'pfix-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'pfix-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'pf
ix-0-Email': ['jondo1@gmail.com', 'jondo2@gmail.com', 'jondo3@gmail.com']}>

Comment: and print(formset)
<input type="hidden" name="pfix-TOTAL_FORMS" value="1" id="id_pfix-TOTAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="pfix
-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" id="id_pfix-INITIAL_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="pfix-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" i
d="id_pfix-MIN_NUM_FORMS" /><input type="hidden" name="pfix-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_pfix-MAX_NUM_FORMS
" />
<tr><th><label for="id_pfix-0-Email">Email:</label></th><td><input type="email" name="pfix-0-Email" value="jondo3
@gmail.com" placeholder="Member&#39;s mail" id="id_pfix-0-Email" /></td></tr>

Comment: I manage to solve it by deleting prefix = 'pfix' I do not know why it messed everyhting ...;( tox for your help  !